# React SPA without routing at all

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, single-page-application

What is the reason of having client side routing in React apps?
Why I can't just use global state to render needed content?
Once I want to change content I could just set this global state via Redux/Context API and rerender.
Is there any other reason to use routers except support of browser navigation back/forward?

Comment: The answers to this will be primarily opinion based -- but both ways are fine. If you have navigation and routing you would want to route based on the url -- let's say a user wants to link someone to your about page ( if your website doesn't have an about page, just think of a page that they might find interesting ) -- would you want them to always navigate from the homepage -> about? The other side of the coin is you wouldn't want routing if the website doesn't necessarily have navigation. For instance a dashboard where the content is the state.

Comment: The biggest advantage of routing is being able to immediately access content via the url.

Answer (score 1):

Well have you really put much thought into it?

- If you use your mouse or keyboard to go back on the browser history (Back button) the browser handles that for you. If you implement client side navigation you can handle everything with ease. Only using state you would have a much harder time and a bunch of holes in your app from just common behaviours.
- Plus accessing pages and stuff through an url.

Just these things that I've enumerated are reason enough to implement client side navigation on a SPA.